# Couchbase throws GetVBucket is implemented only for VBucketNodeLocator

Tags: .net, memcached, couchbase

I have started getting this error

```
GetVBucket is implemented only for VBucketNodeLocator
```

Here is the code:

```
 var couchbaseClient = new CouchbaseClient();
 var isRunning = couchbaseClient.KeyExists("job-started"); //Error here
```

Here is my config:

```
 <couchbase>
    <servers bucket="unittests">
      <add uri="http://localhost:8091/pools" />
      <add uri="http://localhost:11211/pools" />
    </servers>
  </couchbase>
```

This has really only started the bucket is a memcache bucket.

**Quick Update**
If I use get instead of exists it works.

Comment: Why your bucket unittests have 2 servers with same hostname??? If you need to access memcached bucket - use Enyim memcached client, if you need to access couchbase bucket use couchbase client. And for each client you need separate configs. I think to get it work you should remove one of servers uri from your config.